# Prove that 91 is pseudoprime to base b.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm quite stuck on this question and would really appreciate anyone who's able to explain the way it's worked out to me!

The full question is 'Let b be an integer coprime to 91. Assume that b is a quadratic residue modulo 91. Prove that 91 is pseudoprime to base b'.

Any help would be much appreciated! I've been staring at this question for a while now.

Comment: What is $p{}{}$?

Comment: Do you need a value for p? It doesn't state one....

Comment: Well, what's it doing there then?

Comment: Oh that's a typo! I meant 91

Answer (score 1):

If $b\equiv x^2\bmod91$, then $b\equiv x^2\bmod 13$ and $7$.

Therefore, $b^6\equiv x^{12}\equiv1\bmod13$ and $7$, assuming $b$ is coprime to $13$ and $7$.

Therefore, $b^6\equiv1\bmod 91$.

Therefore $b^{90}\equiv 1\bmod 91$; i.e., $91$ is a pseudoprime to base $b$.

Comment: Well, if $91|b-x^2$, then $13|b-x^2$ and $7|b-x^2$, because $13|91$ and $7|91$ (divisibility is a transitive relation); $x^{12}\equiv1 \bmod 13$ and $7$ assuming $x$ is coprime to $13$ and $7$ is due to Fermat's little theorem